# cakephp routes for multilanguage website

Tags: url, cakephp, routes, multilingual

I want to make a multilanguage site in cakephp, it is written [cake's webiste](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#localization-in-cakephp) the way of url structure can be like using specific subdomains like `en.example.com, fra.example.com` or using a prefix to the url, as it is on the official page on the above link. I do not prefer using subdomains, and so I need to do this

```
http://example.com/en/posts/view

http://example.com/fr/posts/view
```

But how should I configure the routes to accomplish this. I want for them to be as on the official website, the language param between the controller and the domain name.

Thanks

Comment: Solution without plugin: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kicaj/2013/01/27/internationalization_with_static_and_dynamic_content_routing_and_switching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the instructions of this plugin https://github.com/cakedc/i18n to set this up.